# How can I read values from HashiCorp Vault into a launch.json debugging configuration for VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, hashicorp-vault, vault

I have a java project that I would like to debug. The project code assumes that certain variables pointing at running services in our remote debugging environment are present, and if they aren't, it will crash.

I'm trying to get debugging working in VSCode, so now the challenge is to get those secret vars from vault and populate them for my debugging session.

I've tried a few approaches, but nothing so far has worked. Below is an example of my latest effort. I tried to use the `inputs` feature with a type of `command`, but it seems that the only valid commands you can use are commands that extensions register with VSCode. I can't just run a shell command.

```json
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Local Debugging",
      "type": "java",
      "mainClass": "com.company.appname",
      "request": "launch",
      "env": {
        "MYVARNAME": "${input:VARNAME}"
      }
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "VARNAME",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "program-to-execute",
      "args": [
        "-arg1",
        "value1"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

`program-to-execute` is the name of a program I have on my local machine that does some custom stuff to eventually execute a read against vault at the path you give it as one of the args. But this approach failed because `program-to-execute` is not a command registered with VSCode internally either by default or by an extension.

In my googling around I haven't found a way to execute an arbitrary shell command and use the result as an env var value for a debugging session.

Comment: have a look at [**Tasks Shell Input**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=augustocdias.tasks-shell-input) and look at the `useSingleResult` property, possibility is to generate the data you want by a shell command in a file and return an empty string and then use [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) to read the file content as key-value, JSON or Yaml file

Comment: @rioV8 That was very helpful and I think it worked as intended. Unfortunately I went a different route to achieve debugging because even after I got those vars to work, the debugger still wouldn't start. I chose instead to start the project with a shell script and remote debug the process. If you submit your suggestion as an answer though I'll accept it because it does answer the question I posed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Tasks Shell Input](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=augustocdias.tasks-shell-input) and look at the `useSingleResult` property

Possibility is to generate the data you want by a shell command in a file and return an empty string and then use [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) to read the file content as key-value, JSON or Yaml file